# Can we verify image dimension in a PDF by Selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a requirement to verify the image dimension of a PDF, which is getting downloaded and saved to a particular location. I am curious to know that, is there any way we can check the image dimension of a PDF using Selenium WebDriver? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium WebDriver is for browser automation. If your requirement is to validate pdf files, contents, images in the pdfs etc, I would suggest you to use the below pdf library.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/introducing-pdfutil-to-compare-pdf-files-extract-resources/